# Searching strings within elements of a list and extracting information

Tags: r, string, list

I am looking to search contents of a file within a list and, where strings match, pull specific information from within that list.

```
#importing files as list
folder <- "~/cars/"
carfiles <- list.files(folder)
len = length(carfiles)
files <- vector(mode = "list", length = len)
```

Each file is a csv, each element of the list is a file and each subelement is a row of the file.

```
#first element == column headers
files[[1]][[1]]
[1] "CarName,RegNumber,CarInfo"

#second element == first row of car info in first file
files[[1]][[2]]
[1] "BMWi3,BM19 XYZ,Colour:White Mileage:9,000 ..."

#third element == second row of car info in first file, etc.
files[[1]][[2]]
[1] "BMWX5,BM19 ABC,Colour:Black Mileage:10,000 ..."
```

For example, here I would like to isolate which sub-element (row in the original Excel file) of the file contains the string "White" and pull the RegNumber information.
Note: I have several hundred files to search through.

This is what I have tried:

```
if (str_detect(files[[i]],"White")==TRUE){
    sapply(files, "[[", 2)
}
```

But it is not isolating the list correctly... which I think is mainly due to my limited knowledge on lists. Any advice on how to identify and extract the information would be helpful.

SHORTENED OUTPUT OF DPUT(HEAD)

```
dput(head(files))
list('Carfile1' = c("CarName,RegNumber,CarInfo", 
"BMWi3,BM19 XYZ,Colour:White Mileage:9,000 ...", 
"BMWX5,BM19 ABC,Colour:Black Mileage:10,000 ...",
"BMWX5,BM19 DEF,Colour:Black Mileage:10,100 ...",
"BMWZ3,BM19 GHI,Colour:Red Mileage:10,102 ..."),
'Carfile2'=c("CarName,RegNumber,CarInfo", 
"AudiA1,BM18 XYZ,Colour:White Mileage:29,000 ...", 
"AudiA2,BM18 ABC,Colour:Black Mileage:30,000 ...",
"AudiA3,BM18 DEF,Colour:Black Mileage:30,100 ...",
"AudiA4,BM18 GHI,Colour:Red Mileage:30,102 ..."))
```

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] of your data by using `dput(head(files))` and pasting the result into the question? Having a reproducible example of your data would make it much easier to test solutions

Comment: If they are .csvs, is there a reason you don't read them in as .csvs?

Comment: The actual files can contain 100 rows each and there are circa 1,000 of them so reading them in this way is more efficient than individually reading them in.
The above output is a shortened and edited version to give a reproducible example.

Comment: even if you have 1000 files (no matter how many rows), working on your data is going to be a lot easier if you read it as data.frames or data.tables